# regex to match multiple times per line and across lines, but not after comment

Tags: regex

I have the following multi-line string:

```
asd \cite[1][2]{foo, bar} asdf \cite{baz, bar}
foo \citet{lorem} % \cite{asd}
foo \citep{ipsum}
\citep{dolor, sit,
amet}
```

I want to match everything inside the curly braces (including `dolor, sit, amet`), but not if it's commented out (after `%`). I don't know what comes after the comment - it may be any number of spaces or characters. I currently use the following regex:

```
 \\cite[tp]?\s*\[?.*?\]?\s*\{(.*?)\}.*?
```

This also matches the commented out part. How can make sure that doesn't happen?

[See example on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/wY5rQ4/4)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a negative look-behind for that :

```
(?<!%)\s\\cite[tp]?\s*\[?.*?\]?\s*\{(.*?)\}.*?
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/wY5rQ4/5)

Comment: This works only if there is a single space between the comment and `\cite`, but there might be any number of spaces or characters between them, so unforunately this won't solve my problem (I use Python, which requires fixed-width look-behinds).